# MU0 register transfer level organization by adding index register

Tags: embedded, computer-architecture, instruction-set, arm9

### Q. Write the MU0 register transfer level organization by adding index register. Give the control logic for the following instructions and explanations.

1. LDA S,X ; A:=mem((S)+[X])
2. STA S,X ; mem((S)+[X]):= A
3. INX ; X:= X+1
4. DEX ; X:=X-1

**This is the control logic table without adding index register:**
[image: This is the control logic table with adding index register]

**This is the RTL design without adding index register:**
[image]

**The question here is to modify the RTL organization shown to include the X register, indicating the new control signals required and then modify the control logic in the table to support indexed addressing.**

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Comment: The question here is to modify the RTL organization shown to include the X register, indicating the new control signals required and then modify the control logic in the table to support indexed addressing.

Comment: that is not a question ... it is a description of a work assignment .... you need to think of a question that you would like to ask, so that someone can answer it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a work assignment, not a question of the poster's own. We're not a service for doing these – we can help you solve your problem, but you'll have to formulate a precise question about what exactly you're stuck with, and what your **own** process of solving it has been so far.